# Security level needed to add a Capability to an iOS App

Tags: xcode

I am looking to add the iCloud capability to an existing iOS app controlled by another entity that I am working with.  Currently they have my account listed as a "member" of their account in the Member Center.  In Xcode when switching the icloud capability on, I am told that the the App Id with the current identifier is not available.

My first thought is that at a "member" level I might not have the correct authority for Xcode to edit the team provisioning profile to add the iCloud entitlement.  Indeed at this level I am prevented from creating a new provisioning profile as this is grayed out in the member center.

In order to add a capability to an existing app do I need them to elevate my permission to an "admin" level or is something else going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was the permission level.  I had them elevate it to "admin" and after I was able to add the proper entitlement.